# Create PostgreSQL 9 role with login (user) just to execute functions

Tags: postgresql

I have been looking for this for years and I have tried everything on the web with no success.

I am able to do it in MSSQL, but I didn´t find a way to do it in PostgreSQL.

What I want to achieve is just create a role with login that cannot create, drop or alter databases, functions, tables or anything else. Just select specific functions.

For example, if I have a table called costumer and two functions called `return_customers()` and `return_time()` I just want a role with login that are able to select `return_customers()` and `select return_time()`. Nothing more than that.

Thank you very much for supporting this useful web site!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Execute this connected to the database you want to configure.

```
-- Create the user.
CREATE ROLE somebody WITH LOGIN PASSWORD '...';

-- Prevent all authenticated users from being able to use the database,
-- unless they have been explicitly granted permission.
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE foo FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;

-- Allow the user to only use the specified functions.
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE foo TO somebody;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION return_customers(), return_time() TO somebody;
```

If you have more schemas than "public" then you will need to add those to the two `REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL ...` statements.

Do not forget that the functions must have been [created with `SECURITY DEFINER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html) or this user will still be unable to execute them, as the contents of the function will be executed with the permissions of this user, instead of the user who created the function.

See:

- [`CREATE FUNCTION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html) particularly `SECURITY DEFINER`
- [`GRANT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html) both for adding users to roles and for assigning access rights to tables, sequences, etc
- [`REVOKE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-revoke.html)
- [`CREATE ROLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrole.html)

Comment: @Ignacio Note that, having revoked rights for `public`, you will have to then `GRANT` rights to your *other* users so they can still access the tables/functions/etc. I strongly recommend creating one or more roles, and making users members of those roles, rather than `GRANT`ing directly to users. You don't have to `GRANT` to the *owner* of objects, but really your app should never be connecting as the database/table owner for day-to-day operations anyway.

Comment: Dear cdhowie and Craig Ringer,
Thank you very much for your answers! I really appreciate them!

Comment: I have been working with Postgre about this topic and noticed some things that I want you to correct me if I am wrong please.

Comment: 1 - It is not recommended to use capital letters in the name of the databases, because the REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES throws an error.

2 - If we create another database we have to revoke all privileges to the limited user or create the objects and REVOKE ALL to public.

Thank you very much in advanced,
Ignacio.

Comment: Please, let me do two last questions.

1 - Is there a way not to allow the limited user to see the definition of the tables and functions?

2 - As we can see in the official documentation it recommends to SET search_path = admin, pg_temp; so the pg_temp schema is searched in the last position in order to user not be able to mask objects. In our case, we have to set it as: SET search_path = public, pg_temp?

I hope this post would be useful for others developers that want to improve the security of theirs PostgreSQL databases.

Thank you very much again!

Comment: I don't think that database object definitions can be hidden without revoking access to the built-in pg_catalog schema, and many things will fail or behave very oddly if you do that.  If you're feeling adventurous you could always try it and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you very much guys! I will continue investigating on this!

Comment: Doesn't adding `SECURITY DEFINER` defeat the point of this? If the `owner` is executing the function on behalf of the `login (user)`, wouldn't this be no better than just granting the `login (user)` to go ham on the database tables directly?

Comment: @JPDamstra No, not even close. If the user only has access to execute the functions, the user can only do what the functions let them do. This is a common pattern in databases: don't let users access sensitive tables directly but create `SECURITY DEFINER` functions that allow the users to perform _some_ operations against the sensitive table which are gated by the functions. The functions can enforce various constraints/checks. Your question is akin to "if we give a user access to a REST API then why not just give them full read+write access to the underlying database?"

Comment: @cdhowie you are correct. I've done subsequent reading since my comment and better understand now. Thanks for the extra info.