# Granting execute on function pg_start_backup in PostgreSQL does not work

Tags: postgresql, function, backup, sql-grant

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-BACKUP-TABLE and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/continuous-archiving.html state that the function pg_start_backup(text, boolean, boolean) can be executed by a superuser or a user which has been granted execute right on the function.

In practice, this doesn't work, because the function is "security invoker". It would only work if it was "security definer". Page [Create PostgreSQL 9 role with login (user) just to execute functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712235/create-postgresql-9-role-with-login-user-just-to-execute-functions) says "functions must have been created with SECURITY DEFINER or this user will still be unable to execute them", which is perfectly correct.

What are the minimal rights I have to give a user on top of "execute on function pg_start_backup" in order to enable him to really execute the function?

Answer (score 0):

Funny enough, the user has to be granted the right to execute this system function in the database (s)he connects to. Although this is a system function identical in every database and doing only things at the cluster level, the right to execute it is saved separately in every single database.

So, if you want to have a special user executing exclusively this function (plus pg_stop_backup(boolean), of course), it would be best to grant it in the postgres database and allow the user to connect only to this database.